# OpenRules RuleEngine JAR not found

Tags: spring-boot, rule-engine

We are currently trying things using openrules rule engine. Particular `JAR` called `openrules ruleengine` is not available anywhere across the source sites.

```
import com.openrules.ruleengine.OpenRulesEngine;
OpenRulesEngine engine = new OpenRulesEngine(fileName);
```

How to add rules dynamically in `openrules` using `Spring boot`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this repository: "http://repository.openmindonline.it". This is where I found the OpenRules jar [openrules](http://repository.openmindonline.it/com/openrules/), I declared the repository tag in the POM and dependencies too according to the version that in here and it worked perfectly for me.